# WPF Mouse.Capture causes window to freeze

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF chart and I'm creating a drag-to-scroll sliding window on the chart. I'm essentially following a MouseDown-MouseMove-MouseUp sequence to track the sliding window movements. I want to manage cases where a MouseMove/MouseUp after a MouseDown occurs outside the chart area. For this, I'm doing a `Mouse.Capture(Chart)` on MouseDown and Releasing the capture on MouseUp. But whenever the MouseDown occurs, my window hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably wrote code that enters a loop on the MouseDown event.  Impossible to tell whether you did or not, you didn't post any code.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
Mouse.Capture (Chart, CaptureMode.SubTree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you handle mouse events not from Window or UserControl or other UIElement, but on specific element that not inherits from UIElement? 
You need use

```
<UserControl x:Class="...
          MouseDown="HandleMouseDown" 
          .../>
```

Instead of

```
<ListBox x:Name="...
            MouseDown="HandleMouseDown"
           .../>
```

Actually, did the window hangs completely or just does not react to mouse clicks (bot do on keyboard)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The problem for me was that the mouse capture for some reason immediately calls the MouseMove event, and I was getting a crash because my mouse move event was expecting a Rectangle to be instantiated in MouseDown.  Of course it was still null.

So the stack looks like this:

```
MouseDown 
  MouseCapture 
    MouseMove
then returns to where it left off in MouseDown
```